# CLLocationManagerDelegate(ibeacon)での観測を端末起動直後から開始する方法をご教示いただきたい

Tags: swift, ibeacon

現在、CLLocationManagerDelegate(ibecon)を用いた、ビーコンアプリを作成しております。

現在、「アプリ稼働時」「バックグラウンド時」「一回起動後、アプリ強制終了後」の３パターンとも
測定出来ていることを確認しております。

次は「端末起動後」でも測定できるようにしたいのですが、方法がわからず
ご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたらご教示いただきたく存じます。

ユーザーの利便性を考えると、端末起動するだけで自動でビーコンを使えるのが
必須だと考えており、どうにか実装したいと考えています。

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/230222

Comment: @suu さん、複数のサイトへ同じ質問を投稿することを「マルチポスト」や「クロスポスト」と言います。スタック・オーバーフローではこのような行為を禁止してはいないものの、質問文でマルチポストしていることに触れ、更に各マルチポスト先で情報の更新を行っていただけるとありがたい、としています。もし他のサイトにも同じような質問をご投稿されていましたら、是非[こちらをご覧ください](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418/19110)。また teratail にも[このような記載](https://teratail.com/help#posted-otherservice)があるのであわせてご覧頂ければ幸いです。